# JSON parsing based on an HTTP query to Google Books doesn't work

Tags: java, android, json, http, parsing

Here's my app. It's supposed to get a JSON String based on a HTTP query to Google Books and show the list of all the found books. But the app always finds nothing.

I use an Android Emulator in Android Studio.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Book>> {
    /** Adapter for the list of earthquakes */
    private BookAdapter mAdapter;

    TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button searchButton = findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText searchText = findViewById(R.id.search_text);
                QueryUtils.setSearchQuery(QueryUtils.getINIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL()
                        + searchText.getText());

                mAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        new ArrayList<Book>());

                ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
                listView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

                // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                // Get details on the currently active default data network
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // If there is a network connection, fetch data
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
                    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

                    // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID 1 and pass in null for
                    // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
                    // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
                    loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, MainActivity.this);
                }
                else {
                    // Otherwise, display error
                    // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
                    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
                    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Update empty state with no connection error message
                    mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No Internet connection.");
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        // Create a new loader for the given URL
        return new BookLoader(this, QueryUtils.getSearchQuery());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<Book>> loader, List<Book> books) {
        // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
        ProgressBar loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Clear the adapter of previous book data
        mAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link Book}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(books);
        }

        // Set empty state text to display "No books found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No books found.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<Book>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Book.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Book {

    private String mTitle;
    private String mAuthor;
    private String mReleaseDate;
    private Bitmap mBookCover;

    public Book(String title, String author, String releaseDate, Bitmap bookCover) {
        mTitle = title;
        mAuthor = author;
        mBookCover = bookCover;
        mReleaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return mAuthor;
    }

    public Bitmap getBookCover() {
        return mBookCover;
    }

    public String getReleaseYear() {
        return mReleaseDate;
    }
}
```

BookAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

    public BookAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0, books);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null)
        {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.book_item, parent, false);
        }

        Book currentBook = getItem(position);

        TextView bookTitleView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        bookTitleView.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

        TextView bookAuthorView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        bookAuthorView.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());

        TextView bookReleaseYearView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_release_year);
        bookReleaseYearView.setText(currentBook.getReleaseYear());

        ImageView bookCoverView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_cover);
        bookCoverView.setImageBitmap(currentBook.getBookCover());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

BookLoader.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

public class BookLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Book>> {

    /** Query URL */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link BookLoader}.
     *
     * @param context of the activity
     * @param url to load data from
     */
    public BookLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    /**
     * This is on a background thread.
     */
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public List<Book> loadInBackground() {
        if (mUrl == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
        List<Book> books = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(mUrl);
        return books;
    }
}
```

QueryUtils.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class QueryUtils {

    private static final String INIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
    private static String searchQuery;

    private QueryUtils() {
    }

    public static String getINIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL() {
        return INIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL;
    }

    public static void setSearchQuery(String searchQuery) {
        QueryUtils.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    public static String getSearchQuery() {
        return searchQuery;
    }

    /**
     * Query the Google Books dataset and return an {@link ArrayList} object to represent a list of books.
     */
    /**
     * Return a list of {@link Book} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing the given JSON response.
     */
    private static List<Book> extractBooksFromJson(String bookJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bookJSON)) {
            Log.e("nojson", "No JSON returned");
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding books to
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the JSON response string. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
            Log.v("success", "JSONObject sucessfully created!");

            // Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "items",
            // which represents a list of items (or books).
            JSONArray bookArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

            // For each book in the bookArray, create a {@link Book} object
            for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length(); i++) {

                // Get a single Book at position i within the list of books
                JSONObject currentBook = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // For a given book, extract the JSONObject associated with the
                // key called "volumeInfo", which represents a list of all information
                // for that book.
                JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

                // Extract the value for the key called "title"
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");

                //Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "authors"
                JSONArray jsonAuthors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();
                StringBuilder authorsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonAuthors.length(); j++)
                {
                    // Add a specific author to the "authors" list
                    // and add it to a the "authorsStringBuilder"
                    authors.add(jsonAuthors.getJSONObject(j).toString());
                    authorsStringBuilder.append(authors.get(j) + ", \n");
                }
                //Remove the last 3 elements in the "authorsStringBuilder"
                authorsStringBuilder.delete(authorsStringBuilder.length() - 3,
                        authorsStringBuilder.length() - 1);
                //Convert StringBuilder to String
                String authorsString = authorsStringBuilder.toString();

                // Extract the value for the key called "publishedDate"
                String releaseDate = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");

                //The link for a book cover
                String imageLink;
                // Get the JSONObject "readingModes" having information about
                // whether or not a given book has a cover
                JSONObject readingModes = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("readingModes");
                // Extract the value for the key called "image"
                boolean hasACover = readingModes.getBoolean("image");
                //Check if a given book has a cover
                if (hasACover)
                {
                    // If yes, then assign a link for the book
                    // to the imageLink
                    imageLink = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks")
                            .getString("thumbnail");
                }
                else
                {
                    // If not, then assign the imageLink the default cover
                    imageLink = "https://books.google.ru/googlebooks/images/no_cover_thumb.gif";
                }

                //Get a book cover
                Bitmap bookCover = getImage(imageLink);

                // Create a new {@link Book} object with the magnitude, location, time,
                // and url from the JSON response.
                Book book = new Book(title, authorsString, releaseDate, bookCover);

                // Add the new {@link Book} to the list of books.
                books.add(book);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the book JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of books
        return books;
    }

    /**
     * Get a book cover.
     */
    /**
     * Return a book cover
     */
    private static Bitmap getImage(String imageLink)
    {
        Bitmap image = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageLink);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
        }

        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Query the Google Books dataset and return a list of {@link Book} objects.
     */
    public static List<Book> fetchEarthquakeData(String requestUrl) {
        // Create URL object
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Book}s
        List<Book> books = extractBooksFromJson(jsonResponse);

        Log.v("QueryUtils", "fetching data");

        // Return the list of {@link book}s
        return books;
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils: : ", "Error with creating URL", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
     */
    private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";

        // If the URL is null, then return early.
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e("", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
     * whole JSON response from the server.
     */
    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

An example query:
[image: An example query:]

Logcat:
[image: Logcat:]

Comment: Your JSON does not match your parsing algorithm. You are trying to turn what appears to be an author name into a JSON object. You might consider using a more modern JSON parser, such as Gson or Moshi, where you can create an object model matching the JSON structure and let the parser fill it in.

Comment: But there's an array of authors' names in Google's API structure. Look at the example: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=search+harry+potter

Why isn't an author name a JSON object?

Comment: A JSON array is a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`. And, based on your error, you are trying to parse a plain string.

Comment: Oh, it's because there are no {} brackets, isn't it? Then I should change
authors.add(jsonAuthors.getJSONObject(j).toString());
to
authors.add(jsonAuthors.getString(j));

Right?